# Why is the standard enthalpy of formation of diamond not zero?

Tags: enthalpy, carbon-allotropes

Why doesn’t diamond have $\Delta H_\mathrm{f}^\circ=0$, when graphite does? Is it something to do with the definition – diamonds can’t really form at STP, even though it is naturally occurring?

Comment: Gives new meaning to the advertising "diamonds are forever". (No, not thermodynamically..)

Comment: Because it was not defined as zero and graphite is of slightly lower enthalpy and is defined as zero. The difference seems to be calculated from heats of combustion. https://atct.anl.gov/Thermochemical%20Data/version%201.118/species/?species_number=951 I wonder if this has been remeasured using pure synthetic diamond and graphene if such exist.

Comment: If you set both to zero, you create a contradiction. The only element that is set to zero in two contexts is hydrogen, with dihydrogen and the aqueous hydrogen ion.

Answer (score 15):

You are on the right track - diamond is not the thermodynamically stable carbon phase at STP. Taking two figures from A.T. Dinsdale, 'SGTE Data for Pure Elements', CALPHAD 15(4) 317-425 (1991) one sees:

[image: Gibbs energy of phases of C relative to graphite]

and

[image: P-T phase diagram for C]

Since graphite is the thermodynamically stable phase of carbon at STP, it is usually selected as the reference phase so it has $\Delta H^0_f = 0$. In the reference above, both absolute Gibbs free energies, as well as free energies with respect to the stable phase at STP, are given for most elements.

Answer (score 8):

Carbon naturally exists as two allotropes, graphite and diamond. By definition, the most stable allotrope at STP (the one with the lowest heat of formation at STP) is assigned a heat of formation of zero.  Graphite has the lower heat of formation and is assigned a heat of formation of zero, while diamond being slightly less stable has a heat of formation of 2.4kJ/mol.